# How do I load a video file into the request to send to youtube?

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload a video file from the device to the YouTube api.  I have the authorization part working, but their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Sending_a_Browser_Upload_API_Request) has me embedding the video data right into the XML payload (between multipart request entity codes), and I'm not entirely clear on what the correct way is to read the file in, encode it, and print it back out to the request.  My assumption is that I need to load it into a byte[] and then spit that back out to string while encoding it, but I'd rather have some authoritative guidance than play trial-and-error games in the dark.

TIA

Comment: No, don't save it as string. That could destroy the file. I would assume you use a POST request with the bin data

Comment: @Cole Johnson, that would be my preference, but if you look at the Documentation link (scroll down a bit for the direct upload example), I'm entirely unclear on how I could make it work with what they're expecting. I've always been mildly confused by the ins and outs of HTTP, what with their headers and content lengths and all... this example kind of bundles all my various points of confusion into one grand example of "what exactly is going on here?!"

Comment: If I'm reading this right, only the video metadata is embedded in the XML payload. In Direct Uploading > Step 3 - Uploading the video file, you just send a few HTTP headers followed by the raw bytes. I'm not saying it's easy, but don't make it any more complicated than it needs to be. Do you know what you are using as your HTTP client? Commons-httpclient?

Comment: @John Watts, yep. I'm in commons (which I have a lot of experience with). My preferred approach would be to just set the headers and then send the video data as the FilePart of a MultipartRequestEntity. I'm looking at the DirectUpload and that's the part I'm actually posting this question about... it looks to me like they want the data printed as part of the XML (after the multipart boundary)... am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: My mistake. I ended up in the Resumable uploads section. Honestly, I think their Resumable API is clearer even if it requires more requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this

```
InputStreamBody metadata = new InputStreamBody(xmlMetadata, "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");
FileBody content = new FileBody(new File("video.mp4"), "application/octet-stream");
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("metadata", metadata);
reqEntity.addPart("content", content);
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
client.execute(post);
```